Python keyboard library call always running (not waiting for keypress)
I'm running a simple python script, using the boppreh/keyboard library. It exits right away instead of waiting for the actual key press to happen:
import keyboard

mc_quit():
  print("all done")
  exit(0)

keyboard.add_hotkey('q',mc_quit())
while True:
  keyboard.read_key()

I have tried putting the add_hotkey function in the loop as well, and get the same result.

YOU called mc_quit (that's what the parentheses after the name of the function do!), and passed its return value (which would be None) to add_hotkey().  Get rid of those parentheses, so that you're passing the function itself.
